# Create a visio 2013 file in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, aspose, visio2013, open-packaging-convention

I want to create a .vsdx file (drawing) using Java. Visio 2013 uses Open Packaging Convention. I don't know from where to start, currently referring this link http://blogs.office.com/2013/01/29/10-tips-for-developers-working-with-the-visio-vsdx-file-format/.

I want to code this program in Eclipse using Java but the above link is explained totally using C# in Visual Studio. I didn't get any Java library for Visio 2013. Can someone help me and give some idea how should I create a .vsdx file in Java which will be supported by Visio 2013?

Comment: The structure and specifications of the vsdx document are publicly available. I will refer to Aspose.Diagram http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/diagramjava/Loading%2C+Saving+and+Converting because I found this tagged with aspose.

Comment: Thanks Razzaq, I think, by Aspose.Diagram i can surely do it.

Comment: but, is there any open-source library? or a way to implement it by own.

Comment: Apache POI libraries for Microsoft documents are very popular and open source. For Visio, they have POI-HDGF, I have added an answer now to list the available libraries.

Answer (score 5):

There are some complications you should be aware of:

1. Visio 2013 file format is specified in an XSD 1.1 schema. This version of XSD is not usable by JAXB, which means you will have to do a lot of manual work to get the data to resolve to Java objects.
2. Aspose.Diagram has quite a few gaps in its functionality based on the brief evaluation I did on it a few weeks ago.
3. The OpenXML4J stuff works fairly well for manipulating the OPC container, but there are a couple of conficts when using JAXB together with this (namely, the relationships within the XML documents themselves are not scooped and must be read in a second, straight DOM, pass).

My approach has been to hack the XSD Schema back down to a 1.0 version and using the N attributes of the objects to switch by type. When I have completed my work, I will be happy to share the XSD which would be usable by JAXB.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the list of Java libraries available for handling Microsoft Visio documents.

1. [Apache POI-HDGF](http://poi.apache.org/hdgf/index.html). It is open source. Reliable and widely used/developed by community.
2. [Aspose.Diagram for Java](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/diagramjava/Product+Overview), but it is a commercial library. Only supports reading vsdx at the moment.

If anyone knows of any other library, please update the answer.

Comment: As per my understanding currently aspose does not support to save .vsdx . it is also disscussed here:- http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/591404/export-to-vsdx-format.aspx

Comment: Yes, you are right, it can only read vsdx. The save feature is expected late this year.

Comment: Wait for any POI expert, I have experience in Aspose components.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So if i want to save a file in vsdx format then do i have to code it by own. I am thinking to use openxml4j to manipulate packaging.